# No ejecuta "app java" en java web contenida en localhost

Tags: java

El probleme es que cuando ingreso al archivo .jnlp me dice que "no se ha podido abrir la aplicación", creé archivo-de-pruebas.jnlp, y exporté un proyecto a .jar el tema es que cuando hago doble click, pareciera como que va a andar y dice"no se ha podido abrir la aplicación". Están tanto el archivo .jnlp como el .jar en la misma carpeta, dentro del localhost, ya los habilité en la parte de seguridad, porque me venía impidiendo correrlo, sin embargo ahora el problema es otro y no sé cual és.

Página de pruebas de java
Axel. Berlot
Programas realizados por mi.

> 

```
//Este localhost es de xamp, osea que está guardado en la carpeta htdocs de xamp, sin funcionar el tomcat, se usa otro?
```

// Instalé el tomcat 7.072 pero no sé dónde guardar la carpeta /java-prueba, sin embargo no sé si es necesario, ya no sé dónde puede estar el error, los permisos de certificados ya los habilité de la config. java.

Página de pruebas de java
Axel. Berlot
Programas realizados por mi.

> 

Comment: Quizás aparezca algún mensaje de error, un log que escriba la aplicación. Esto proveería más información sobre los errores que tuvo la aplicación al iniciar.

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Principal
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Algo me dice que has puesto como clase inicial el nombre simple de tu clase `Principal` cuando debes colocar el nombre completo, el cual es el nombre del paquete y la clase p.e. `com.paquete.donde.esta.tu.clase.Principal`

Comment: no va, lo estoy intentando y no va, esta es la dirección desde el principio hasta el final del archivo donde está la clase main: /ventana/src/controlador/ventanaPrincipal.java   donde ventana es la carpeta, src es un paquete, controlador es otro paquete y ventanaPrincipal es el archivo, acabo de intentar de todas las formas y no va es frustrante.

Comment: Ve a tu clase `Principal` y mira en la primera línea lo que dice: `package <nombre del paquete>`. Ese es el que debes usar.

Comment: perdon, una pregunta, para verlo en localhost, necesito usar tomcat? porque veo que hablan de tomcat y yo solo tengo activado apache y mysql.

Comment: "com.controlador.ventanaPrincipal" lo puse bien y sin embargo no anda. por esopregunto lo de tomcat.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza entiendo que soy un poco pesado con este tema, pero no le encuentro solución, voy a editar el código arriba para demostrar cómo lo tengo al momento, sin funcionar.